# Securing a two node type cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to figure out how I can secure my two nodetype cluster.
I have read all of MS documentations but most of it is about one nodetype clusters.

I have a two nodetype cluster, backend and frontend. My frontend have a web running on port 443.

When I created the cluster using the portal, I got a ARM template containing almost two identical sets of rules/items, one for my backend and one for my frontend.
As an example, the rules on both of the load balansers are identical, RDP and everything.

Since my backend nodes are only going to be called from my frontend over secure RPC, and not have any public facing endpoints, do I even need the backend load balanser? What can be deleted/removed/closed to improve the security of the cluster?

Is a vanilla, portal created, two nodetype cluster "secure" enough to be used in production if there are no special regulations?

(I know it "depends", but Im looking for the general consensus. Compare it to securing IIS and you know what I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Service Fabric does not require the internal load balancer for the second node type, so you can remove its public IP and should be able to delete it entirely if you wish.
2. Look into setting up network security groups if you want to further restrict traffic. Information on NSGs is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-security-groups/) and an example with Service Fabric is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/02/15/configuring-service-fabric-security-hardened-cluster-alb-and-ilb/). A full SF template is posted [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-nsg-cluster-65-node-3-nodetype).